# Strange behavior of lambdas list in Python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I wrote this simple Python code

```
PP = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
F0 = lambda x,y: x
FF = [
    lambda u: F0(*(u[i] for i in p)) for p in PP
]
print(FF[0]([1, 2]))
print(FF[1]([1, 2]))
```

And I got

```
2
2
```

While I expected

```
1
2
```

With some other tests with more permutations I could observe that FF is indeed a list of the right length but contains only copies of the last function we want.
Someone could explain me why ??

Comment: You are creating a list of 2 identical functions, both of which have the *name* `p`, not a value *of* `p`, in their definition.

Comment: Thx, I see the problem. Very strange language.. Do you know how can I use the value of `p` instead of the name ?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I can add the argument p=p to put the value of p in the closure of the lambda

Comment: It's not that strange: the body of a lambda expression isn't evaluated any more than the body of a `def` statement is.